# ndb.toplevel for python method versus request handler

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

The Google App Engine doc states that "As a convenience, you can decorate the request handler with @ndb.toplevel."

Can @ndb.toplevel be used with python methods that are not request
handlers?

I have a python method mymethod() that calls ndb.put_multi_async(), and mymethod() gets called in unit tests.  I would like a call to mymethod() to complete the put_multi_async() before proceeding.  To get that effect, can I decorate mymethod() with @ndb.toplevel?  Doing so seems to ensure that put_multi_async() completes before mymethod() returns, but I wanted to double check that there are not any unintentional side-effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the whole `tasklets` module [source](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datastore-ndb-python/blob/681b3ee430cc1c7d04d1d9f2d8ecec709e9e5387/ndb/tasklets.py), from which `toplevel` comes, must be studied to confirm that (to the best of my knowledge, it's not documented elsewhere than in the module's own docstrings), but having done so I can see no side effect emerging from using `toplevel` to decorate a method that's not a handler.